# Я новичок в unity. Был бы благодарен если помогли решить проблему

Tags: массивы, unity3d

У меня вылезает ошибка: IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
MapManager.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/MapManager.cs:20)

```
public static int countUnlockedMap = 1;
public MapButtonManager[] mapButton;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++){
        if(i < countUnlockedMap){
            transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = mapButton[i].GetComponent<MapButtonManager>().unlockedIcon;
            transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
        }else
        {
            transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = mapButton[i].GetComponent<MapButtonManager>().lockedIcon;
            transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: полный стейк-трейс всегда приводите

Comment: А как мне это сделать Сергей?

Comment: копируете все, что есть. Пример: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Serge\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    lines = file.readlines().rstrip()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'"

Answer (score 0):

Ваша `i` в строчке `transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = mapButton[i].GetComponent<MapButtonManager>().unlockedIcon;` превышает кол-во элементов массива